# AdBlock bloquea mis img y mis estilos.css de mi pagina web

Tags: css, html5

Hola que tal? quisiera saber si alguien puede ayudarme, estoy creando un sitio web y tanto las imagenes como mi archivo css con estilos estan alojados en el server y son bloqueados por adblock hay alguna solucion para evitar esto?Saludos!
Probe de todo incluso elimine todo solo agregue un archivo index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Document</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, 
initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
   <img src="p8.jpg" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

en donde en el servidor no hay nada mas que el archivo index.html y una imagen p8.jpg y aun asi me bloquea la imagen y no la muestra

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** [edit] la pregunta con lo que haya intentado.

Comment: ¿Como estas nombrando a los archivos? Tienes que añadir más información a tu pregunta, así como el código o más detalles sobre tu problema.

Comment: Como indica @EdgarGutiérrez, falta información en la pregunta. AdBlock puede bloquear los ficheros si su ruta contiene "ad" o "pub", conocer los nombres/rutas de los ficheros bloqueados sería interesante, también habría que ver si tienes alguna configuración en la extensión. Completa el [tour] y lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: revisa los nombres de acuerdo a los filtros https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet , podes tambien probar con ublock origin que trae una lista de los filtros activos y de ahi saber exactamente por qué te filtra las cosas

Comment: Quería saber si logro arreglar este problema ya que me pasa lo mismo con mi web hecha en PHP (Codeigniter) Básicamente el Adblock no permite que se muestre ninguna imagen de mi sitio,